# Adding randomness to looping UIView animation block

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to make an animation in iOS using the animateWithDuration: method.

I'm moving an image(a simple picture of a cloud in a UIImageView) across the screen and then having that animation run in a loop and I want to change the speed(duration) each time it crosses the screen.

I've tried a couple ways but both behave incorrectly for me.

I first though I could use the UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat like this:

```
[UIImageView animateWithDuration:arc4random() % 10 + 1
                           delay:0.0
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                      animations:^{
 //moving the cloud across the screen here
}
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Done!");
}];
```

But this does not seem to call the arc4random() again to reset the duration...i.e. the cloud will cross the screen at a random speed only every time the app is started, not every time the animation loops.

I then tried using the completion block to fire the animation again like this:

```
-(void)animateMethod
{
[UIImageView animateWithDuration:arc4random() % 10 + 1
                           delay:0.0
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                      animations:^{
 //moving the cloud across the screen here
}
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Done!");
    [self animateMethod];
}];
}
```

This gives me the effect I'm looking for, but when I push to another view using a navigation controller the completion block gets fired in an unending loop it seems(my log gets spammed with "Done!")

Anyone know the way to get the desired effect I want the proper way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track. The key is that you need to only loop if the animation finished not if it failed. So you need to check if the `finished` `BOOL` is true before telling it to loop.

```
-(void)animateMethod
{
    [UIImageView animateWithDuration:arc4random() % 10 + 1
                               delay:0.0
                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                          animations:^{
     //moving the cloud across the screen here
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            NSLog(@"Done!");
            [self animateMethod];
        }
    }];
}
```

This method works great for very simple animations like this and when you're only doing a few, like maybe 3-5 clouds at a time. Anything more than this and you'll probably want to setup your own animation loop using an NSTimer or CADisplayLink and adjusting the clouds frames in it. Its a much more manual way but it will get you some nice animations even in UIKit.

Comment: Yup, that fixed my problem.. I knew I was on the right track.  I'm just starting to learn animation in iOS so thanks for the tip on NSTimer and CADisplayLink too.